# Types for function that applys name of function and arguments

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, typescript-types

I'm trying to type in proper way function that applys name of function and argumens for this function. After that apply it and return the result. Here the code:

```js
const sum = (a: number, b: number) => a + b
const concat = (a: string, b: string, c: string) => a + b + c

const funs = {
    sum,
    concat
}

type Keys = 'sum' | 'concat'

type Args<T> = T extends (...args: infer R) => any ? R : never

type Sum = Args<typeof sum>
type Concat = Args<typeof concat>

function apply<K extends Keys>(funKey: K, ...args: Args<typeof funs[K]>) {
    // here I get the error 'An argument for 'a' was not provided.'
    return funs[funKey](...args)
}

const test1 = apply('sum', 1, 2)
const test2 = apply('concat', 'str1', 'str2', 'str3' )
```

Inside funciton `apply` I get the error 'An argument for 'a' was not provided.'.
How I can get rid of this error?

[Link to playgound](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=22&ssc=1&pln=23&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCuBbGBeGAKAhgLhmJARgKYBOANDAbvosSQJSoB8MmMA1JQFCiSy-BMsNFlzQSASzABzClThRJMisDGKp0xihZtOBDjGBce4aDABm8SKhgBvLjEdwkZB04FCuAX2NQAngAORDAA0kR+EDYA5AiIUTAAPjBRHlBRvoHBAIIk0hAAPAAqLGiFMEQAHlBEYAAmkegAdM2YuRC4UuakMABKWjpgfjAA-L0w1EQAbqQZQTAAykg2OXn5-kEg5s6ITFzrwQDC4ILCMCsF+5uGx0K7XJZgwFAS4KwBAQA2fvkh5VU19VC4QgTHQDzCflwIQozUarTyuHOa0yVweEAA2iEALpMRj2JwwEhEKDwEhgCxWDHg8JYpotNr0bzGXhmarQACMNkw7y+6BiSCiFHZFAATIyWbA2VARVyeX4+alBclxOylTFFCK1eIAMzxRlAA)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler will not be able to understand that this is type safe because it generally does not reason very well about assignability for types that depend on as-yet-unspecified generic type parameters.  There is an existing GitHub issue, [microsoft/TypeScript#24085](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085), that describes this situation.

In fact, it is possible (but not very likely) that in your function, `K` might be inferred as `Keys` itself instead of either `"sum"` or `"concat"`.  If you do this:

```
const oops = apply(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "sum" : "concat", "a", "b", "c"); // oopsie
console.log(oops); // 50% chance of "abc", 50% chance of "ab"
```

then you see that the compiler is *technically* correct that what you're doing isn't type safe.  You'd like to tell the compiler that `K` will be *exactly one of the members of* `Keys`, and you can't.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) for a feature suggestion that would allow this.

Anyway, the compiler can't view the `funKey` parameter and the `args` rest parameter as having *correlated* types.  And even if it could, it's not great at maintaining the correlation, see [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) for more about that.

It also can't understand compute the return type, so you'll have to annotate it.  You can use the [`ReturnType<F>` utility type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypet) for this.  Note that there's also a [`Parameters<F>` utility type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterst) which you can use instead of writing `Args<F>` yourself.

---

So when it comes down to it, you will just have to tell the compiler that what you are doing is type safe (you won't call `apply()` on some union-typed `funKey`, right?), because it can't verify it.  And to do that you need something like a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions).  The easiest one to use here is good old [`any`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any):

```
type Funs = typeof funs;

function apply<K extends Keys>(funKey: K, ...args: Parameters<Funs[K]>): ReturnType<Funs[K]> {
    return (funs[funKey] as any)(...args);
}
```

This will allow you to do crazy things like `return (funs[funKey] as any)(true)`, so you should be careful.  Slightly more type safe but considerably more complicated is to represent `funs[funKey]` as a function which somehow accepts either the arguments expected by each function, and which returns *both* of the return types.  Like this:

```
type WidenFunc<T> = ((x: T) => void) extends ((x: (...args: infer A) => infer R) => any) ?
    (...args: A) => R : never;

function apply<K extends Keys>(funKey: K, ...args: Parameters<Funs[K]>): ReturnType<Funs[K]> {
    return (funs[funKey] as WidenFunc<Funs[Keys]>)(...args);
}
```

Here `WidenFunc<Funs[Keys]>` is `(...args: [number, number] | [string, string, string]) => number & string`.  That's kind of a nonsense function type, but at least it will complain if you pass it an argument like `(true)` instead of `(...args)`.

---

Anyway, either of those should work:

```
const test1 = apply('sum', 1, 2) // number
const test2 = apply('concat', 'str1', 'str2', 'str3') // string
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCuBbGBeGAKAhgLhmJARgKYBOANDAbvosSQJSoB8MmMA1JQFCiSy-BMsNFlzQSASzABzClThRJMisDGKp0xihZtOBDjGBce4aDABm8SKhgBvLjEdwkZB04FCuAX2NQAngAORDAA0kR+EDYA5AiIUTAAPjBRHlBRXP5BMABiVpFomUQg5hZ5ANy+gcEA6hIAJkRguWDAADwAKiwi6AAeuO1aLABuIPWMRD1QjXWR6L246AB0y5gk0hC4UuakMACCgzBbOwBKB5hgfowA-G6OSytrG3sHxzDUREOkFVyWLVAS4FYAQCABs-K0QjAJlMwDNQuEIEx0L8wn5cCEKMtFqt1rgAAqrTCIIhTEgQVrNCAAbRCAF0mPRcMcSfASGB2lUKXkafS7LcYIUctkbLUGk0rG1KTSEfT+SQWWyML9qSjwrTWJFRY1mpLuaiIPT6PdsY96BUfD8Jf9AZhgWCAEwQqGTaaRfVI1Vo0KYh64mAEkhEkmkclSukMpkK9mcsO8+xOGDyqCssBK7me9WYSLnS7GnEQM3eYy8MwgEABfJA0F+dAAWSEAAtFoHYSBEOhGK0YAAGRYAVhgVxgACJYsO3iPUsOKMPMNORwR58PgMOzTAAPTrmBlisSIgmSAgEFERYgkDSdA7gtlDdbvvdgCkhgb52AwWKI8wBBXFHvT+AL4tO+JSzouxamLAUzQAAjDYtrVugMRIFEFDQRQ9qMJueCEKQB5mFBUD2nBdo1ik4CCGkFAxIo0Eock4j2nR1EkAAzFEmFbuIGjGDAQA)