# Typescript - using a dictionary of functions

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a dictionary of functions as follows:

```
type Test = {
  first: (args: { a: string }) => void;
  second: (args: { b: number }) => void;
};

const library: Test = {
  first: (args: { a: string}) => console.log(args),
  second: (args: { b: number}) => console.log(args),
};

const choice = <K extends keyof Test>(
  page: K, options: Parameters<Test[K]>[0],
) => library[page](options); // typescript complains here by underlining 'options' with error:
// Property 'a' is missing in type '{ b: number; }' but required in type '{ a: string; }'

// Later we use choice
choice('first', { a: 'test' }); // however here it is enforced that the args can only 
// be 'a' for 'first' and 'b' for 'second' as I would expect and is the desired outcome
```

For the sake of furthering my understanding, I would like to know why this happens, and whether there is a correct way of asking this of TS.

Comment: Honestly just `as` your way out of it.  *Technically* `K` can be the union `'first' | 'second'` so *technically* you can have a situation where the `options` don't match the `page`.

Comment: I'll throw it on the pile at [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60194677/types-for-function-that-applys-name-of-function-and-arguments for more info.

Comment: To illustrate @LindaPaiste's point.
Let's say you have a function `function randomPage(): keyof Test { return Math.random() > .5 ? 'first' : 'second'; }`, and you use it when calling choice: `choice(randomPage(), ???)`

The compiler (nor you) would not be able to know the value of `page: K` in the choice function because it's a runtime value now.